# How to select all users except ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the model Users

get

`params[:ids]`

for those users which don't need

Seen similar

`User.where.not(id: params[:id])`

This cool! But id but not ids :(  working

Comment: I dont get it. Are you facing some issue with the query?

Comment: the not is not really working for me I don't really know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
User.where.not(id: params[:ids])
```

Here `params` is the parameter sent to server during the request, and values in `params` then can accessed with keys, in your case it is `:ids`: `params[:ids]` not `:id`(`params[:id]`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are performing the request with something like `GET /users?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3`, you are on the correct path with:

```
User.where.not(id: params[:ids])
```

`User.where.not(id: [1,2,3])`
translates to
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."id" NOT IN (1, 2, 3))` in my tests on ruby 2.1.3 rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for you:

```
User.where("id NOT in (#params[:ids])")
```

for example:

```
User.where("id NOT in (2,3,4)")
```